# Open Chrome extension popup when URL google meet opens

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-meet

I want that my chrome extension sidebar opens automatically, when the URL contains meet.google.com. Can someone point me to the errors in my code?

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function () {
  // Set up the event listener for webNavigation
     chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function (details) {
    // Check if the URL is "https://meet.google.com/"
    if (details.url === "https://meet.google.com") {
      // Open the extension popup
      chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
          target: { tabId: tabs[0].id },
          func: openIframeSidebarOnGoogleMeet,
        });
      });
    }
  });
});

// Function to be executed in the context of the page
function openIframeSidebarOnGoogleMeet() {
  // Call your function to open the sidebar
  openIframeSidebar("https://standbyclone.bubbleapps.io/meetings", "400px");
}
```

Comment: Remove lines with `onInstalled` and `query` entirely, use details.tabId in executeScript, embed openIframeSidebar inside openIframeSidebarOnGoogleMeet.